# OpenGL ES 3.0 and APPLE_clip_distance extension

Tags: ios, opengl-es

According to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html) APPLE_clip_distance extension is present on OpenGL ES 3.0 and iPhone 6+ hardware. I'm trying to use this by first enabling it in code and then using in the shader.

I can query the maximum number of clipping planes by doing

```
GLint i;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_CLIP_DISTANCES_APPLE, &i);
printf("i: %d\n", i);
```

and this prints out 8.

When trying to use this in the shader like this:

```
const mediump int gl_MaxClipDistances = 8;
out highp float gl_ClipDistance[gl_MaxClipDistances];
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 0:24: Identifier name 'gl_MaxClipDistances' cannot start with 'gl_'
ERROR: 0:25: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_MaxClipDistances'
ERROR: 0:33: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_ClipDistance'
```

[This document](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_clip_distance.txt) describes the extension and as far as I understand it I'm supposed to redeclare the clip distance array due to the fact that I'm using ES 3.0:

```
(1) GLSL 300 doesn't support unsized arrays, how should gl_ClipDistance
be sized?

  RESOLVED: For maximal compatibility, it works like ES2/desktop,
  remaining unsized until sized by direct access or explicitly
  redeclared.  Language describing this behavior must be added to the
  extension specification since it's gone from the base language
  specification.
```

Also declaring it like this:

```
out highp float gl_ClipDistance[];
```

gives this error:

```
ERROR: 0:25: Unsized array 'gl_ClipDistance' requires sized initializer under GLSL 300
ERROR: 0:33: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_ClipDistance'
```

Does somebody have a working example of this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to do is specify in your shader code that it relies on this extension. Close to the start of the vertex shader, after the `#version`, add the corresponding `#extension` directive:

```
#version 300 es
#extension GL_APPLE_clip_distance : require
```

Then, the way I read the extension spec, you use a declaration looking like this to size `gl_ClipDistance`:

```
out highp float gl_ClipDistance[4];
```

where the constant matches the number of clip planes you want to use. Note that, unlike the code posted in the question, you do **not** redefine `gl_MaxClipDistances`. Once you require the extension, the constant should already be defined.

You can **use** the constant if you want to use the maximum supported number of clip planes:

```
out highp float gl_ClipDistance[gl_MaxClipDistances];
```