# Isnt clipping planes work in kivy opengl?

Tags: kivy

Im trying to make render to texture for reflection and refration texture for water shader... but glClipPlane is not defined in kivy opengl.. Here are some ScreenShots

[Test with PyOpengl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkAKJ.png)

[Test with kivy Opengl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLiqJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Clipping-planes in OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408855/clipping-planes-in-opengl-es-2-0), it looks like this wasn't part of OpenGL ES 2.0, which Kivy nominally targets. If you do want to use it, you probably can, but it isn't part of Kivy's exposed API (these low level opengl calls are usually considered internal to Kivy).

Comment: I was thinking to use shader for this...Thanks for answer :)